# Прямая речь, которая включает четверостишие

Tags: пунктуация

Если прямая речь включает начало фразы, описывающей услышанные стихи, и одно четверостишие из самого стихотворения, то требуют ли правила прерывать прямую речь, вроде:

```
"Я услышала такое в стихах:" -- сказала она.

Раз два три четыре пять
Я иду искать

"И я сразу вспомнила что-то".
```

Или же правила требуют оставить всё это одним блоком прямой речи? В это случае "сказала она" и "я" во второй прямой речи автор бы пропустила:

```
"Я услышала такое в стихах:

Раз два три четыре пять
Я иду искать

И сразу вспомнила что-то", -- сказала она.
```

Comment: спасибо большое, что отредактировали! Так гораздо понятней. И добро пожаловать на Russian SE )

Comment: Can you please explain why you are creating different user each time you are asking a question? It's not agains rules per se to my knowledge however sockpuppetting is.

Comment: @shabunc The profile says the user is unregistered. So perpetual cookies loss is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

> — Я услышала такое в стихах, — сказала она. — «Раз, два, три, четыре, пять — я иду искать». И сразу вспомнила что-то.

Оформляется прямая речь обычно так. Цитируемое стихотворение включается в кавычках в этот же блок. Если перенесете слова автора в конец, то немного другой вариант с двоеточием.

> — Я услышала такое в стихах: «Раз, два, три, четыре, пять — я иду искать». И сразу вспомнила что-то, — сказала она.

Comment: Строго говоря, это у вас диалог, а не прямая речь.

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks are generally not inserted for any intervention, be it end of paragraph or author's speech:

"Она глупа, - заметила я. - И слепа".

"...Она глупа.
И слепа к тому же".

I trust verses should be no exception to the general trend, and thus the second version is correct.